# I have made a bit of code that gets your resolution in Windows, how do I make it print it in an f string?

Tags: python, windows

I have made a bit of Python code that gets your resolution in Windows, how do I make it print it in an f string?

```
# libraries
import ctypes

# get screen resolution
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), 'x', user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)

# list to store resolution and the x that is between them
items = []

# add resolution to list
for item in screensize:
    resolution = (str(item))
    items.append(item)

# print resolution
for item in items:
    print(item, end='')
```

Its output is 1920x1080, but I need it to be like because it's going to be among other code

```
print(f'''Resolution: {screen_resolution}''')
User: {getuser()}
```

as I am trying to remake neofetch. Unless there is a better way of getting your resolution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `screensize` definition to:

```
screenwidth, screenheight = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

then skip *all* the rest of the code and replace it with:

```
print(f'Resolution: {screenwidth}x{screenheight}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add you results to a string if you want like this:

```
import ctypes
# get screen resolution
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), 'x', user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
full_res = ''
# list to store resolution and the x that is between them
items = []
# add resolution to list
for item in screensize:
    resolution = (str(item))
    items.append(item)
# print resolution
for item in items:
    full_res += str(item)
print(f"Resolution: {full_res}")
```

or a better way imo

```
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
print(str(screensize[0]) + 'x' + str(screensize[1]))
```